# what goes wrong with Opcahce and xcache

Tags: php, zend-framework, nginx, opcache, xcache

my environment

`ubuntu 14.04` , `php 5.5` , `nginx 1.76`

i am using both `opcache` and `xcache` concurrently

```
PHP 5.5.19-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) (built: Nov 19 2014 19:33:43) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with XCache v4.0.0-dev, Copyright (c) 2005-2013, by mOo
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
    with XCache Optimizer v4.0.0-dev, Copyright (c) 2005-2013, by mOo
    with XCache Cacher v4.0.0-dev, Copyright (c) 2005-2013, by mOo
    with XCache Coverager v4.0.0-dev, Copyright (c) 2005-2013, by mOo
```

i am just wondering can i use both opcache and xcache at the same time .. i dont know whether this allowed or not ? I know that both do almost the same job, but not sure if that would make any difference on the performance and speed.

suggestions invited ? so can i use both ?

Comment: Using two opcaches at the same time is almost certainly going to cause conflicts, and there isn't really any reason I can think of to try using two opcaches at the same time

Comment: No you can't use Opcache and Xcache together, so don't even try.

Comment: thanks for your replies. So i should not use both together

Comment: @TerryE 

can i use both opcache and memchached together ?

Comment: Yes, or even Opcache, APCu and memcached.  Opcache is a opcode cache only -- that is it caches the compiled output from the PHP internal compile phase.  APCu and memcached are *data* caches; the former is in-process using an SMA; and the latter out of process.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar environment (Ubuntu 14.04, PHP 5.6, XCache 3.2, Apache). In my tests when Zend and XCache enabled, the response time is the same of the XCache only. When I disable XCache, and use only Zend OPcache the time resquest reduced in 10ms. Maybe you be try OPCache + Redis (for variables), or use only XCache if the time response not make diference for you.